# Wicket : Manually set value of a DateTextField

Tags: java, wicket, wicket-7

My problem is, that i want to clear the value of my DatetextField html input whenever my user uncheck a checkbox.
I have an AjaxCheckBox and currently just have my condition checking if the value equals false.

```
@Override
protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget ajaxRequestTarget) {
    if(!this.getModelObject()){
       ???
    }
}
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just set the modelValue of your DatetextField and updated via ajax:

```
datetextField.setModelObject​(null);
ajaxRequestTarget.add(datetextField);
```

Don't forget to set a markup id for the datetextField:

```
datetextField.setOutputMarkupId​(true);
```

Comment: Since DatetextField require a Date object, I put ```null``` instead of ```""``` and it workd. I was lacking the ```ajaxRequestTarget.add(datetextField);```

Comment: @cocoall I've edited my answer to use null. Thanks.

Comment: In my experience with wicket simply setting the model object to null to clear a form component often doesn't work because wicket still has some value saved in the input or converted input that has not yet been written to the model. So when clearing a FormComponent I always make sure to also call the `clearInput()` method of said component as well. So I'd personally recommend adding `datetextField.clearInput();` just to be on the safe side.